# Capture X-Path of a dom element using different location strategies

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath

I tried to capture x-path of a dom element with the help of Firebug source.
It has clearly defined the relevant function as `getElementXPath()` and I was able get the xpath by passing the Web Element.
But it returns a single x-path and the x-path strategy is unpredictable.
It can be a absolute path or relative path with ID.

Say this is our simple HTML page:

```
    <html>
     <body>
       <form>
         First name: <input id="fname" type="text" name="firstname"><br>
         Last name: <input id="lname" type="text" name="lastname">
       </form> 
     </body>
    </html>
```

I am searching for the xpath of the 1st text box here:

```
    //*[@id="fname"]
```

This is what we get using firebug; as well as using my script which uses the `getElementXPath()` of Firebug code.

But in Selenium IDE there is a drop down box with a list of suggested paths for a single web element.

```
    id=fname ()          - id
    name=firstname       - name
    css=#fname           - css
    //input[@id='fname'] - xpath:attributes
    //input              - xpath:position
```

I went through it's code and found that `Google AJAXSLT` is the default library they are using. And also it says : use “javascript-xpath” for the newer, faster engine.
I checked both scripts but so far I was not able to find any direct function which returns an array of paths.

Is there any simple standalone function like Firebug's `getElementXPath()` in those libraries?

Answer (score 0):

If i correctly understand you want to try your xpaths in firebug, then try [FirePath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/)

Example: [image]

Comment: No.. this is not what I am expecting to do. I need to do this grammatically. I am passing the DOM element.. I need a function to return a array of xpaths represent this element.